# how to disregard counting a certain word in python dictionary

Tags: python

Hello I'm wondering how to make a dictionary that will not count the word 'the' or definitely remove it from the dictionary so i came up in this code:

```
counts = dict()
print('Enter a line of text:')
line = input('')
words = line.split()
print('Words:', words)
print('counting...')
for word in words :
    if words != 'the':
        counts[word]= counts.get(word,0)+1
    else:
        counts[word] = counts.get(word,0)
print('Counts', counts)
```

can you help me to make it right?

Comment: Change `words` to `word` in `if words != 'the':`

Comment: Oops. Sorry that I missed that 'words' should be 'word' in the conditional. - is that actually your only problem?  I think there's still no reason for the 'else' clause, but maybe I don't know what you're trying to do when you see 'the'.

Answer (score 1):

While @Steve's answer is correct, the code can be a bit prettified and simplified:

```
from collections import Counter

line = input('Enter a line of text:')
words = line.split()

print('Words:', words)
print('counting...')

c = Counter(words)
del c['the'] # remove 'the' key from counter

print('Counts', dict(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this? :

```
counts = dict()
print('Enter a line of text:')
line = input('')
words = line.split()
print('Words:', words)
print('counting...')
for word in words :
    if word != 'the':
        counts[word]= counts.get(word,0)+1
print('Counts', counts)
```

Comment: it still counts the word 'the'

Comment: oh i see i've put the variable instead of the element's name

Comment: It seems you were just trying to do something with 'the'. My change was to just ignore 'the' completely. - I don't know what you're talking about now.  What is "the element's name"? - Your code seemed just fine as is for counting words.  You might want to lowercase each word if you don't want capitalization to matter.

Comment: In `if words != 'the':`, `words` will never equal `"the"` as `words` is a list.

Comment: Ha!  You're right.  That's just a typeo from the OP that I retained.  I didn't try this code...I assumed it was working except that 'the' was mishandled.  @Jansen, was this part of your problem all along?  Sorry I missed that logic error.